# Script to update Monit config based on amount of processors

Tags: monit

I am wanting to build a script to install a monit config to monitor load avg on a server. Is there a way to say "Use this threshold if the server has 1 CPU or use this threshold if the server has 2 CPU's?
I have roughly 24 servers and adding more every day that I would love to just install the file and it adapts to the server or if a server is upgraded to have more CPU's. 
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Probably you could also consider using a provisioning tool like Ansible to deploy and manage your configuration according to the facts of the servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just see the [latest release notes on Monit 5.26.0](https://mmonit.com/monit/changes/). There is a new option to check per Core.

```
if loadavg(1m) per core > 2 then alert
if loadavg(1m) > 8 then alert # same test on a 4 core system
if loadavg(1m) > 18 then alert # same test on a 9 core system
```

The only problem is that most OS' Repo will not provide a version that recent. So you might end up compiling it your own or the create the config-file with a bash script like

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Integers only!
percore=2

cores=$(grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l)
load=$(expr $cores \* $percore)

echo "if loadavg(1m) > ${load} then alert" >> myMonitRcTemporaryFile
```

this - for sure - will not react if CPUs are added (like in a VM)...

Comment: That's awesome! I did not see they added that ability yet. Thank You for showing me that, this solves the issue completely.

Comment: Great! Could you [mark that answer as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please?